# Is there any possibility to select (highlight) text in more than one recycler view item at once?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textselection

I am working on android app where I want to implement simple text file reader. I am using recyclerView to show the text. I chose the recyclerView for speed, since when I loaded larger file into one textView, the app crashed. So one line of the file is one item in the recyclerView. Now I'd like to add the text selection and highlight on long click. I have easily managed to do it for one item (one line) - I have added the attribute `android:textIsSelectable="true"` to the item container. But that logically allows to select only text from one item at once.

Is there any possibility to select text in more than one recycler view item at once?

Thank you in advance.

This is the layout of the reader:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/file_list_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
                    />

        </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And this is the item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: The result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Just give the selected text a different color. Or change background color of clicked item.

Comment: @blackapps thank you, but that is not what I want. A want to select more lines at once when I long press. Highlighting one item is not an issue.

Comment: You can select as many items as you want if you follow what i suggested. (I knew you want to select more so why do you even think that it was for one item only?).

Comment: `A want to select more lines at once` Ehhh.. You mean: i want to be able to select more items. One by one. For every item the user has to click. Is itt that? For a next click you dont want to loose the other clicks.

Comment: Since the `TextViews` are separate items of Recycler view i am not sure if its possible . have you tried using a `WebView` ? or it overflows too ?

Comment: @blackapps I have added a picture to the original post to show what I'd like to achieve. I get your solution, thank you very much for that, but it would not allow to select e.g. only part of the first and last line, like it is shown on the image. I guess that the recyclerView architecture is not suited for this purpose - but I wanted to give it a try.

Comment: @ADM I did not, thank you for your advice, I will try it!

Comment: `but it would not allow to select e.g. only part ` No. But first  that was not possible already with one item and  android:textIsSelectable="true"  and second you did not tell us that you wanted that. Wrong informed.

Comment: @blackapps sorry, it was hard for me to explain it.. Thank you for your time and effort, I really appreciate it.